# how to list names of all docker images from self hosted Gitlab server

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ce

how to get the list that contains names with tags of all docker images from self hosted `gitlab-ce` server, so that i can run a script to download them all at once?

Though I would prefer to get this list from an gitlab API call, any other solution will also be appreciated.

(currently it returns max 50 items from one gitlab  API call, but I want all)

Answer (score 2):

Use the [container registry API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/container_registry.html).

There is a special catalog endpoint that can be used to [list all container repositories](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/container_registry.html#listing-all-container-repositories) in the whole instance. For each repository, you can use the [repository details API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/container_registry.html#get-details-of-a-single-repository) which will contain all the tags for each repository, which you can then use to pull each image.

> it returns max 50 items from one gitlab API call, but I want all)

Many GitLab endpoints are paginated, meaning you have to make multiple requests if there are many objects you're trying to get. See the [pagination documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/#pagination) for details on how to leverage pagination.